# Could not open Play Store App on OLG Joy

Tags: applications, google-play-store

What may be the reason? The same happens when I try to open Whatsapp app.

[image: smaller image]

Comment: it would be better if you set English as your language so that others can understand

Comment: "While fetching info from server, error occured, RH-O1, Try Again"